# How do I save a panel/frame to a file and then read it?

Tags: java, file, serialization, panel

Here is my problem:

I'm building 2 applications:

1. One would be the 'editor', and I would put some panels, buttons, text areas, etc.
2. The 2nd one will be the 'application', where I can interact with those components

I'm thinking if I can save the main panel of the editor (and it has the other components inside) into a `File` using `FileOutputStream` and then read it on the other application.

I've tried so. Now I have a file with a lot of bytes, but how would I read it and build it again into the components?

I'm not sure on how to do this, and I couldn't find the correct terms to do the searching.

Comment: Did you store it in the file using an ObjectOutputStream, making use of serialization?  If so, you can read the object in using an ObjectInputStream wrapped around a FileInputStream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you are looking for is called [serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html). Here is an [example using Java Swing](http://java-demos.blogspot.com/2012/10/store-jframe-size-location-using-serialization.html).